# How to work with energy model in ns3 as in ns2 for energy modifying protocol as energy aware?

Tags: networking, protocols, adhoc, ns-3, ad-hoc-network

After going through some examples and number simulation, I was not able to implement the energy efficient routing on ns3 like I performed in ns2.

The documentation on 'nsnam.org/wiki/energy_model' states:

> An energy model has been implemented in ns2 (ns2 energy model) but is yet to be implemented in ns3.

Is this true? Or is the documentation not updated for latest version of ns3?

At the same place the documentation has:

> if a protocol is energy-aware, i.e. its operation depends on the energy level, it cannot be effectively simulated without an energy model.

I was able to perform the energy aware simulation on ns2 by modifying the aodv source file. When I tried to perform a similar simulation on ns3 with a similar modification it somehow didn't work.

How can this be done on ns3?

Answer (score 0):

There is an energy module on ns-3 : https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/energy.html

Try looking under src/energy/examples/ for some good sample files that can get you started. There are some sample files under src/wifi/ as well.